# can't use pandas, TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

First, I'm a novice python coder and also new to stack overflow.  Apologies if I'm doing anything incorrectly.

I have a hw problem where I'm reading a csv file which contains voting data, each individual's vote.  I'm supposed to use loops (can't use pandas) to sum each candidates vote totals.  I'm using a for loop to go through each item then using an if statement to see if the candidate is on the summation list.  The master list of voter data is poll_reader.  The candidate list is the 3rd column.  The list I'm creating for each candidate is candidates, with the candidate in the 1st column.  When I run it, the error I'm getting is:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Referring to the If statement line.  I thought I was referencing the data correctly, but obviously not.  Am I referencing the data incorrectly at the if statement?  Here's my code

```
# Import modules needed, OS and CSV
import os
import csv

# create the path name to access the bank data in a csv file and use it
pollpath = os.path.join( 'Resources', 'election_data.csv')
candidates = ['Ro', 2]

# open the csv to begin looping through
with open(pollpath) as polldata:
    poll_reader = csv.reader(polldata, delimiter = ',')
    # skip the header row
    header = next(poll_reader)
    
    # initiate candidates list. 
    # Column [0] will be candidate name, column [1] will be votes
    already_listed = False
    
    # read the rows of each voters choice
    for row in poll_reader:
        # start with a for loop to then turn into a list comprehension.
        # Read through the netflix_reader data row by row,
        # use an if to test if the data is in the list of candidates, 
        # then sum their votes, whether existing or not
        # candidate or a new one
        for cndidt in candidates:
            print(cndidt[0])
#             if cndidt[0] == row[2]:
#                 candidates[1] += 1
#                 already_listed = True
#                 break
#             else:
#                 already_listed = False
#         if already_listed == False:
#             candidates[0].append(row[2])
#             candidates[1] += 1
#             break
```

Comment: The question is "what is the type of `cndidt`"? - Apparently, it is not something that can be subscripted (that you can apply `[x]` to).  Why don't you put the line `print(type(cndidt))` just before the offending line and see what you get.

Comment: Can you post the remaining code from where you are collecting the data for candidates? probably this is where the problem is coming from. The candidates list is not set properly or incorrect data than what you are expected.

Comment: Please post how the file looks like, or do a minimum example.

Comment: Yes, I'm discovering that as I'm looping through the data the candidates list is going one dimensional on me.  I'll edit and put in the whole code.

Comment: Jsut updated the original post with all of my code